# HP Laptop Installation problem: "The system is running in low-graphics mode"

Tags: hp

I have HP laptop with 4GB RAM and 1GB AMD Radeon graphics. I installed Ubuntu 13.10. After the installation system restarts and stuck with the message "The system is running in low-graphics mode".

Comment: did you install any graphics drivers on ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a HP laptop and this helped me to solve my problem!

[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)